# Mysql joins - returning twice the number supposed

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on a script where an auction should be able to contain several products. A product has a normal price, which is summed up for all the products in an auction and then return as the auction "package" normal price.

My problem is, that my test auction has a normal price of $150, but the query returns $300, which means I have made a mistake somewhere. I have used the whole night trying to find a solution - but unsuccessful. Does anyone have a clue?

```
SELECT 
    a.AuctionName as A_name, 
    c.CategoryName as C_name, 
    a.AuctionEndDate as A_enddate, 
    a.AuctionOfferPrice as A_price, 
    SUM(p.ProductPrice) as A_normalprice, 
    s.StoreName as S_name 
FROM A_Auctions a 
RIGHT JOIN 
    A_Categories c 
    ON c.CategoryID = :category_id 
INNER JOIN 
    P_ProductsAuctions ppa 
    ON ppa.Auct_AuctionID = a.AuctionID 
RIGHT JOIN 
    P_Products p 
    ON p.ProductID = ppa.Prod_ProductID 
RIGHT JOIN 
    P_Attributes pa 
    ON pa.Cate_CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
RIGHT JOIN 
    P_AttributeValues pav 
    ON pa.AttributeID = pav.Attr_AttributeID 
LEFT JOIN 
    S_Stores s ON a.Stor_StoreID = s.StoreID 
WHERE 
    a.Cate_CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
    AND ((pa.InternationalName = 'param1' AND pav.AttributeValue = 'value1') OR (pa.InternationalName = 'param1' AND pav.AttributeValue = 'value2')) 
    AND ((pa.InternationalName = 'param2' AND pav.AttributeValue = 'value1') OR (pa.InternationalName = 'param1' AND pav.AttributeValue = 'value2'))
GROUP BY 
    p.ProductID, a.AuctionID, pa.AttributeID ORDER BY a.AuctionID DESC 
LIMIT 0,20
```

Here is my table structure:

A_Auctions:

```
AuctionID   int(15)         
AuctionName varchar(256)        
AuctionDescription  text        
AuctionPicture  text        
AuctionOfferPrice   decimal(15,2)           
AuctionMinimumPrice decimal(15,2)           
AuctionStartDate    datetime            
AuctionEndDate  datetime            
AuctionTimeInterval time            
AuctionNextInterval datetime            
AuctionPercentageChange decimal(5,2)            
Cate_CategoryID int(15)         
Prod_ProductID  int(15)         
Stor_StoreID    int(15)         
StUs_StoreUserID    int(15)         
date_added  datetime
```

P_Products:

```
ProductID   int(15)         
ProductName varchar(256)        
ProductDescription  text        
ProductPictureLink  longtext    
ProductPrice    decimal(25,2)           
ProductStatus   int(3)          
ProductGroupID  int(15)         
Cate_CategoryID int(15)         
StUs_UserID int(15)         
added_date  datetime
```

P_ProductsAuctions (storing the 1:Many relation between Auctions and Products):

```
Auct_AuctionID  int(15)         
Prod_ProductID  int(15)
```

P_Attributes (The table for the different variants of a product):

```
AttributeID int(15)         
Auct_AuctionID  int(15)         
Cate_CategoryID int(15)         
AttributeName   varchar(256)        
InternationalName   varchar(256)
```

EDIT:
- The problem seems to be with the parameters in P_Attributes and P_AttributeValues, because when I add 1 parameter more to the query, the price is being $150 higher - so $300 with 1 parameter, $450 with 2 parameters, $600 with 3 parameters and so on...

EDIT 2:

Find a SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d223f/1

EDIT 3:

My output should be:

A_NAME -> Testing

C_NAME -> Test

A_ENDDATE -> September, 09 2012 22:00:00-0400

A_PRICE -> 250

A_NORMALPRICE -> 150

S_NAME -> (null)

Thanks in advance,

denlau.

Comment: can you show the structure of all the tables

Comment: coosal: Now I think there is better conditions for solving! :)

Comment: have you tried a right join instead of inner on your products?

Comment: Now updated with a where clause that shows how I use my parameters..
The right join didn't do the job :/

Comment: show your create table statment and make your practice to use http://sqlfiddle.com so that it is easy for people to understand and answer you quickly

Comment: Hello raheel - I will try to learn to use sqlfiddle.com..

Comment: sql is fiddle is used to create structure and there is a panel in which you can query when you create structure on sql fiddle copy link and paste in your question so that people can access it and it will be available

Comment: Raheel: I have added a sqlfiddle in the topic-text.. Hope it makes sense.
/denlau

Comment: Can you show your output what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you have issues with your attributes table.  The problem is that you have multiple attributes causing another row to be returned for each attribute.  Your GROUP BY combines these rows and adds all of the prices to the SUM.

If you just add pav.AttributeValue to your SELECT and GROUP BY clauses, you can see this in action, its $150 for size 43 and $150 for size 44.

You are going to have to refactor this to do a subselect to get the product IDs.  I haven't fully understood your schema, but you may want something like this:

```
    SELECT
  a.AuctionID ,
  c.categoryid,
  p.ProductID ,
  a.AuctionID ,
  ppa.Auct_AuctionID,


  s.storeID,

  a.AuctionName AS A_name,
  c.CategoryName AS C_name,
  a.AuctionEndDate AS A_enddate,
  a.AuctionOfferPrice AS A_price,
  sum(p.ProductPrice) as A_normalprice,
  p.ProductPrice AS A_normalprice,
  s.StoreName AS S_name
FROM
  A_Auctions a
RIGHT JOIN
  A_Categories c
  ON c.CategoryID = '1'
INNER JOIN
  P_ProductsAuctions ppa
  ON ppa.Auct_AuctionID = a.AuctionID
LEFT JOIN
  P_Products p
  ON p.ProductID = ppa.Prod_ProductID
LEFT JOIN
  P_Attributes pa
  ON pa.Cate_CategoryID = c.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN
  S_Stores s
  ON a.Stor_StoreID = s.StoreID

INNER JOIN
  (SELECT distinct Cate_CategoryID FROM P_AttributeValues pav INNER JOIN P_Attributes pa ON pa.AttributeID = pav.Attr_AttributeID 
    WHERE
      (pa.InternationalName = 'size'
      AND pav.AttributeValue = '43')
    OR
      (pa.InternationalName = 'size'
      AND pav.AttributeValue = '44')
  ) pav2  ON pav2.Cate_CategoryID = c.CategoryID 

WHERE
a.Cate_CategoryID = c.CategoryID

GROUP BY productid, auctionid, categoryid
ORDER BY
  a.AuctionID DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```